# Is setting SSH-Key in github necessary?

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

**Hi Devs, I am new to git and I have some questions about GitHub.
Please answer if possible.**

- Q1)Can anyone push into my repo if it is public and if I don't set a **ssh-key** for my account?
- Q2)Using HTTPS url for push and pull is safe or not?
- Q3)Why git is not asking for authentication even if I have not set any **ssh-key**?
- Q4)How can I protect my repo from outsiders so that they can only see it and they'll not be able to change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering the main question the response is "*no, it isn't*"

About the other questions:

- Q1) Can anyone push into my repo if it is public and if I don't set a ssh-key for my account?

  - No, if your repository is **public** everybody can `clone` it and work on it in his local working copy but none can push new commits on your repository unless you explicitly invite them to (Settings -> Manage access -> Invite a collaborator) and they accept the invitation.

    You add a collaborator if he is a member of your team and you want him to work directly on your project (hopefully you share a workflow to use branches properly).

    Another way to collaborate is to `fork` your project and ask to merge new features / fixes through a `pull request`. This is used by external collaborators.
- Q2) Using HTTPS url for push and pull is safe or not?

  - It's safe.
    The main difference is that if you work with a remote set with a HTTPS url you need to pass your credentials every time you need a remote operation (`push`, `pull`, `fetch`, ...).

    You can save your credentials in a `.git-credentials` file in **Linux** (but you'll have your password stored in a not encrypted text file) or store them in the Credential manager in **Windows**.
- Q3) Why git is not asking for authentication even if I have not set any ssh-key?

  - If you are performing a `clone` you don't need to pass your credentials since your repository is public.

    If you are performing a `push` the only reason is that you are working on **Windows** and you already specified your credentials once.  Now they are stored in the credential manger (look at the answer to Q2).
- Q4) How can I protect my repo from outsiders so that they can only see it and they'll not be able to change it?

  - People can't change it unless you don't authorize them (look at the answer to Q1)

Comment: If I may, just one clarification: 
"If you are performing a clone you don't need to pass your credentials since your repository is public." - this can be true depending on repo setup and _how_ you request to clone. For example, specifically as far as ssh goes (op's question), if you type git clone github.com/lala (which is a shorthand that will resolve to "git clone ssh://yourusername@github.com/lala") you _must_ provide ssh key as anonymous requests are not supported by ssh protocol (regardless whether you access github.com or any other server). SSH protocol can only transfer encrypted data.

Answer (score 2):

Q1) Can anyone push into my repo if it is public and if i not set a ssh-key for my account?
- Nope, not all can push in your repo (this is pertaining to Github) only you, however some may do a pull request.

Q2) Using Html url for push and pull is safe of not?
- It is safe, it still needs your credentials before doing the operations.

Q3) Why git not asking for authentication even i have not set any ssh-key?
- You only need to set it up one time, I think you have set global Git Configs in your case.

Q4)How to Protect my repo form outsider so they can only see it and not able to change it?
- They cannot change it but if they see it, they can copy it and upload it on their own.